# Народа или народу?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее: "много народа" или "много народу"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Из словаря грамматических вариантов русского языка** (АН,Институт русского языка,2004г).

Учитывая тенденцию развития в соотношении форм -а и -у, следует рекомендовать флексию -а как нормативную основную форму родительного падежа во всех значениях и для всех стилей литературного языка. Флексия же -у представляет собой второстепенную вариантную форму, свойственную прежде всего устной речи, в письменных же стилях она держится преимущественно во фразеологии и в уменьшительных формах.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите говорить/писать правильно, то нужно держаться точности, знать о различиях, понимать тонкости Родительного падежа. Ну, видимо, общественность этого не понимает и не знает, стало быть у неё свои правила, отличные от самого Русского языка. Не стоит бояться их правил, они всё равно сдуются под напором точности... 
Итак, прежде надо рассмотреть другой пример. Родительный падеж и "чая - чаю". 
Когда предлагается чай, например: "вам чай?" либо "хотите чай?", то слово "чай", в Именительном падеже, говорит о том, что предлагается напиток с названием "чай", именно "чай", а не другой напиток. В Родительном падеже предложение имеет запрос на другие признаки, а именно: "хотите чаю?" - "чаю" говорит о запросе на количество, объём емкости, в котором подать напиток (полный стакан, половина стакана...); "хотите чая?" - "чая" говорит о запросе в выборе: марок чая, крепости чая, цвете чая (зелёный либо чёрный), температуре чая (горячий либо холодный). 
Родительный падеж и его окончания задают чёткий, различаемый запрос на количество и на свойство. Поэтому: 
Сочетание «много народУ» служит для указания на количественное числительное. Сочетание же «много народаА» служит для указания на разношёрстность, разнообразность собравшихся.